# Wildcard ".*.a" on Unix matches what?

Tags: unix

If I execute the command

```
mv .*.a dir/
```

what exactly will be moved where? How far would this recurse up?

Comment: Belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

This moves all files in the current directory that match `.*.a` into `dir`. There's no recursion, except that directories matching the pattern are also moved in their entirety (but that's not recursion, because a directory is just a special type of file that can be moved in one operation).

Answer (score 0):

The glob `.*.a` matches any file or directory whose name begins with a dot (`.`), then zero or more characters (`*`), and ends in another dot and an `a`. So for example, it will match any of

```
.foo.a
..a
```

But not

```
.foo.abar
foo.a
.foo.b
```

So, any files or directories matching that glob will be moved to he directory `dir`. No recursion will happen but if the glob matches directories, their contents will also be moved.